# How to make ARRAYFORMULA work with SUMIFS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a `SUMIFS` formula that works fine, but I have to drag it down to populate every column, which is quite impractical for the amount of data I have in my spreadsheet, therefore I want to turn it into an `ARRAYFORMULA`. The formula is supposed to calculate how many of a product was purchased in a month. It currently looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS(All!$N$3:$N, All!$AG$3:$AG, ">=1/1/2018", All!$AG$3:$AG, "<=31/1/2018", All!$L$3:$L, $A2)
```

`All!N` contains the quantity of an item the customer purchased, `All!AG` contains the date, and `All!L` contains the product code which is checked against the product code in column `A`.

I tried simply doing

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(All!$N$3:$N, All!$AG$3:$AG, ">=1/1/2018", All!$AG$3:$AG, "<=31/1/2018", All!$L$3:$L, $A$2:$A))
```

but that only works for cell `A2` - it just prints the same result as the other formula and doesn't carry on down the column, which is what I want it to do. That solution worked with a `SUMIF` formula I have (it does the same thing but doesn't check the date) but it won't work with `SUMIFS`. I'm not sure why and I'm not the best at troubleshooting these spreadsheet formulas so I'm hoping someone can help.

Update: Here is a dummy sheet showing the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pX-icbJxmy8A0jhKLnSRxhZTLRgYFG_iU2BOQrseCCg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 I'm unable to share a copy of the spreadsheet as it contains sensitive information

Comment: in that case pls create a dummy sheet with fake data reproducing your original setup/issue - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create

Comment: @player0 Here is a dummy sheet (I have also added it to the post): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pX-icbJxmy8A0jhKLnSRxhZTLRgYFG_iU2BOQrseCCg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **B2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN($A$2:$A), IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A, 
 QUERY({All!$B$3:$D}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
  where Col3 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0), 0), ))
```

paste in **C2** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN($A$2:$A), IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A, 
 QUERY({All!$B$3:$D}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) 
  where Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(        C$1,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(C$1, 0), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''", 0), 2, 0), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLf9upJbTGT8ZYZoA_-i2g7mWBi-EGNo9imfb6tEIuY/edit#gid=10965737)